# JQuery Ajax prepended data disappears

Tags: codepen

So I'm building a wikipedia viewer and trying to import data from wikipedia and prepend it to an unordered list (#output).

The problem arises when I type something in the input field and hit the #search button. For a split second the content is listed then it disappears, like I'm refreshing the page.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#search").click(function() {

    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ searchTerm +"&limit=5&callback=?"

    $.ajax({      
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {        
        $("#output").prepend("<li><a href = "+ data[3][i] +">"+ data[1][i] +"</a><p>"+ data[2][i] +"</p></li>");
        };

      },
      error: function(errorMessage){
        alert("Error");
      }


    });
  });

});
```

I'm doing this in Codepen for a freeCodeCamp project. Here is the link to the pen I wrote in, so that you can see for yourself what the problem is:

[Wikipedia Viewer](https://codepen.io/Zsoltbanyai/pen/aEmajy?editors=1011)

This is my first post, hope I'm doing it right. Tried to search for the solution but couldn't solve it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You form is being submitted when you press the submit button.

You can capture the `onSubmit` event of the form and return false to prevent it from being submitted. You can add an id to your form to be able to select it easily with jQuery.

```
       $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
          return false;
        });

       <form id="myForm" class = "pure-form pure-form-aligned">
         <button class = "button-error pure-button" id = "search">Submit</button>
         <input class = "pure-input-2-3" id = "searchTerm">
         <ul id = "output"></ul>
       </form>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mprYGy?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a **form** and it's getting submitted when you press your button.

Change your **form** element to a **div** since you're using **Ajax**.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpENYy?editors=1011

```
       <div class = "pure-form pure-form-aligned">
         <button class = "button-error pure-button" id = "search">Submit</button>
         <input class = "pure-input-2-3" id = "searchTerm">
         <ul id = "output"></ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: OMG that was fast. Thank you! This is where I know I'm still a beginner :)

Comment: There's another way too, if you want to keep the "Enter" button functionality."

Comment: How do you mean? With this solution I won't be able to invoke the button functionality by pressing enter? I'm working on that code as we speak.

Comment: I added another solution with the onSubmit event capture.